# Modal for tr - different id index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

I have an index page with different software in a table.
I want to display additional information (in a modal) when we click on a tr.

Everything works but I have the information of a single software that appears in my modal and is the same for each tr.

I would like to display the information of each software in the corresponding modals.

My script :

```
$(".clickable").click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('no-click')) {
        $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

My view :

```
<% @nonpremium.each do |software| %>
  <table>
    <tr class="clickable">
        <td class="hey1">
          <%= link_to software_path(software), class: "no-click" do %>
            <%= image_tag software.logo.url(:medium), class:"no-click"%>
          <% end %>
        </td>

        <td class="hey3">
          <h6><%= software.slogan %></h6>
          <p><%= software.largeslogan %></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>



<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= link_to software.software_name, software_path(software), class:"no-click" %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I tried something like this in my script, but it does not work ..

```
    $(".clickable").click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('no-click')) {
        $('#exampleModal-<%= @software.id %>').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Thx for you help

EDIT :

Controller/pages

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :click, only: :index

    def home
        @softwares = Software.all.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc )
        @premium = Software.includes(:user).where(users: { subscribed: true }).order("RANDOM()").limit(2)
        @nonpremium = @softwares - @premium
    end

    def search
            @softwares = Software.ransack(name_cont: params[:q]).result(distinct: true)
            @categories = Category.ransack(name_cont: params[:q]).result(distinct: true)

            respond_to do |format|
                format.html {}
                format.json {
                @softwares    = @softwares.limit(5)
                @categories = @categories.limit(5)
                }
            end
    end
end
```

EDIT 2 :

I have the desired result by putting in my table the information that I want to recover, then I put a "display: none".

```
<style>
        td.test {
    display:none;
    }
</style>

<td class="test">
      <span><%= software.software_description %></span>
      <span><%= get_video_iframe(software.youtube_id) %></span>
</td>
```

Then I get the information from my table in my script:

```
$(".clickable").click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('no-click')) {
     var description = this.childNodes[3].innerHTML;
     var name = this.childNodes[5].innerHTML;
     document.getElementById("myModalName").innerHTML = name;
     document.getElementById("myModalDesc").innerHTML = description;
     $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

For then displayed in my modal:

```
...
  <div class="modal-body" id="myModalName">
   Name
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" id="myModalDesc">
    Description
  </div>
...
```

There is probably better to do, but being a beginner is how I achieve the desired result.

However I would like to post videos in my modals.

Am I not going to overload my home page by hiding youtube videos with my display: none?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use `erb` in your script (unless this is in a `script` tag within your view, in which case your code should work) - better using a data attribute. For example, if you update your `tr` to the following:

```
<%= content_tag :tr, class: "clickable", data: { software_id: @software.id } do %>
  # the rest of your code within the tr
<% end %>
# Equivalent of using:
# <tr class="clickable" data-software_id="<%= @software.id %>">
```

This attaches the relevant `software_id` to the `tr` in the DOM. You can then use the following in your script, accessing this new attribute:

```
$(".clickable").click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('no-click')) {
    $('#exampleModal-' + $(e.target).data('software_id')).modal('show');
  }
});
```

And everything should work as desired.

Let me know how you get on or if you have any questions. Hope this helps!

---

Edit based on your comment:

That error you're seeing will come because `@software` is `nil` and you are, therefore, attempting to call `id` on `nil`.

It's a common error, and means to need to ensure `@software` is correctly set in your controller. If you post your controller code, I might be able to help with this.

Alternatively, you can 'safely' try the method, using `@software&.id` with newer versions of Ruby / Rails (or `@software.try(:id)` on older versions). However, that's not likely to be helpful here, more of a side note :)

---

Edit 2:

So, in your controller, you're not actually assigning the singular `@software`, rather the plural `@softwares`:

```
   @softwares = Software.all.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc )
   @premium = Software.includes(:user).where(users: { subscribed: true }).order("RANDOM()").limit(2)
   @nonpremium = @softwares - @premium
```

Then, in your view, you're looping through `@nonpremium` using the local variable `software`. So, you can either:

- assign `@software` in the controller if it should *always* use the same data in the modal
- go back to the previous option, assigning a data attribute to the `tr`, which is what I'd recommend. Using that should work, although you'll need to alter the code to use `software` without the `@` to address the correct variable.

I.E.

```
<%= content_tag :tr, class: "clickable", data: { software_id: software.id } do %>
  # the rest of your code within the tr
<% end %>
```

This ensures the script addresses the click based on the element clicked, and pulls the `id` directly from there, which is within the scope of your `software` loop.

That do it for ya?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I use a script tag in my view.
However when I make these changes I get an error:

undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

<tr class="clickable" data-software_id="<%= @software.id %>">

I am a beginner and there may be something that I do not understand correctly ..

Comment: Thanks @ClydeT - I've updated my answer to reflect this. That will be your issue. If you update the question as requested I'll be happy to try and help.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer @SRack, I edited my question by adding my controller pages.
But I do not understand the result nil knowing that I have already posted the information of the software on my home page?
So why this nil result in the modal?

Comment: Updated @ClydeT :)

Comment: Did this help in the end @ClydeT?

Comment: Hello @SRack, sorry for the delay but big weekend world cup with Belgium :) I have just done several tests and research about it but I still have not found the solution ... Your solution does not send me more error but nothing happens .. the modal does not respond? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Hope you enjoyed it :) Ah OK, shame - try putting some logging in the script (i.e. `console.log('clicked')`, log the element, etc. Good luck with it!

Comment: Hello @SRack, I edited my question with a solution that allows me to have the result I want.
Do not hesitate to tell me your opinion :)